# <footer> Text displaying beside the <section> element content instead of displaying in new line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to design a simple ecommerce website, in that my `footer` tag text is displayed right beside the `section` tag. I have no idea where I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
    <aside id="categories">
        <header id="headings" class="background_div">Categories</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Staples</li>
                <li>Oils</li>
                <li>Vegetables</li>
                <li>Fruits</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>    
    </aside>

    <div id="bestsellers">
        <header id="headings" class="background_div">Bestsellers</header>
        <article class="productarticle">
            <figure>
                <img src="faded-short-sleeve-tshirts.jpg" alt="cabbage"/>               
            </figure>
            <div class="align_text">
                <header id="headings">
                    <span class="productarticlename">Cabbage 1</span>
                </header>
                <p class="productprice">$10</p>
                <div class="addtocart">
                    Add to Cart
                </div>
            </div>    
        </article>

        <!-- 4 More Article Tags will be included here -->   
    </div>    
</section>

<footer>
    <div clas="heading">This is footer text</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
   #content{
        width:  100% px;
        display: block;
    }

    .carousel_img{
        width: 1000px;   
    }

    #headings{
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #categories{
        float: left;
    }    
    #bestsellers{
        float: left;
        margin-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 0 px;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20 px;
    }

    .background_div{
        background: lightgreen;    
    }

    .productarticle{
        float: left;
    }

    .align_text{
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Please help me. I want the content in section tag and the text in footer tag to be displayed in seperate lines.

**[JS-FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sai_Upadhyayula/n1jjqyga/)**

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/n1jjqyga/1/) what you want?

Comment: yes @Lal . Can you please provide the explanation as an anwer ?

Comment: Please see my answer for explanantion @Sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/n1jjqyga/1/)

Since your `#content` contains of floated elements, you also need to float the `#content` div. Thus add a `float:left;` to `#content`.

Now to clear this float effect from the footer, you need to add `clear:both;` to your footer CSS. Thus the changed CSS would be like

```
#content{
    width:  100% px;
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
footer{
    clear:both;
}
```